# How do I enable SSL for custom domains on appengine?

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl

How do I activate SSL for custom domains on Google Appengine?

The instructions I have read, at https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/ssl or https://support.google.com/a/answer/2644334?hl=en , seem to refer to an old version of the admin console for Google Apps.

I looked at https://support.google.com/a/answer/2644334?hl=en , but on the current console, if I do Security > Advanced Settings > Set up SSO, there is no place where it asks for the AppEngine Application ID.

I looked at https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/ssl .  It directs me to go to the Admin Console of my App domain, and to find a Domain Settings tab and then go to the SSL subtab.  There is no Domain Settings tab, however, and the "Domains" tab only allows me to add domains (without http / https mention).

So, how do I setup SSL for my appengine app that uses a custom domain?

Note: this question has been asked already on StackOverflow, some years ago, but the google dashboards have changed since then, and the information I could find is no longer relevant.

Answer (score 15):

Ok, so that other people can avoid wasting as much time as I did. 
When you go to the admin console for your domain, you need to click on Security, but NOT on Advanced settings.  Rather, pay attention to the small "Show more" below the other options. If you click that, "SSL for Custom Domains" will magically appear. 
No thanks to Google for this horrible user interface.

Comment: +1 for finding the answer yourself and reporting back.

Comment: I'd like to give a supplementary explanation. The "Show more" is not visible until you add a sub domain by "Add new URL" in your GoogleApps console. Be sure NOT to do the custom domain setting on GAE admin console. Otherwise when you try to add it, the cryptic error message emerges: "We are unable to process your request at this time. Please try again later. (Error #1000)".

Answer (score 0):

Hallelujah to Luca.  I've wasted a day on this.  I had already added the custom domain in the GAE app engine console and was getting the cryptic "We are unable to process your request at this time. Please try again later. (Error #1000)" message.

I wasn't able to assign the certificate to my custom domain.  The custom domain wouldn't show in the list in the GAE Security Settings (custom domain) until after removing the custom domain from the GAE console.

Answer (score -1):

AppEngine **Introducing managed SSL for Google App Engine** for customs domains and it will be got activated automatically, for already added domains **please remove it and add once again**

More Information-

- https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2017/09/introducing-managed-SSL-for-Google-App-Engine.html
- https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/securing-custom-domains-with-ssl