# Can't assign SSL certificate to Google App Engine app

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl, ssl-certificate

I've gone through all the steps of setting up an SSL certificate on a Google App Engine app with custom domain.  It worked for our test app (URL: test.mycompany.com).  Now I'm went through the exact same process with our demo site (URL: demo.mycompany.com).  Google is not letting me assign the URL to the certificate.

[image]

Comment: Did you already added the demo site url to your Google Apps Appengine Applications ?

Comment: No, I forgot.  Added it and problem still persists.

Comment: Note that the app works with https at its appspot address.  It just doesn't work at the custom domain address.  I assume this is because I can't assign the custom domain (see screen shot).

Comment: One more thing, in Google Apps Appengine Applications I noticed my test site (which works) has an additional URL (test.mycompany.com).  When I try to add an additional URL (demo.mycompany.com) for the demo app I get this error message, "We are unable to process your request at this time. Please try again later. (Error #1000)".

Answer (score 2):

Figured this out.  This posting was most helpful: [How do I enable SSL for custom domains on appengine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22140809/how-do-i-enable-ssl-for-custom-domains-on-appengine/26241181#26241181).

In short, first add the custom domain in the Google Apps admin.  Don't add it to the Google App Engine Console.  Then in the Google Apps Security settings upload the certificate and assign the URL to the certificate.  Adding the custom domain to Google Apps Console after doing this.

Having the custom domain defined in GAE admin console first, produces the error, "We are unable to process your request at this time. Please try again later. (Error #1000)".